# SqlException and I'm not able to resolve it

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception, sql-server-2012, sqlexception

I'm facing a problem when I tried to execute a query. I'm getting this error:

> Cannot find either column "m" or the user-defined function or aggregate "m.gender", or the name is ambiguous

Code:

```
 myConnection.Open()
 Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader() /* Problem is here */

 Return myReader
```

The query runs fine when I execute directly in SQL Server. Problem is when it is executed on the button click event in my application. (VB.NET)

Pls, check my whole query

```
    SELECT pt.color as Color, m.model As Model, m.gender AS Gender,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 1 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Jan,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 2 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Feb, 

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 3 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Mar, 

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 4 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Apr,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 5 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) May,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 6 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Jun,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 7 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Jul,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 8 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Ago,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 9 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Sep,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 10 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Oct,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 11 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Nov,

       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(o.data_ins) = 12 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
       END) Dec

FROM   models m 
       INNER JOIN product_type pt 
               ON m.model_id = pt.model_id
       INNER JOIN product_orders po 
               ON pt.producttype_id = po.producttype_id 
       INNER JOIN orders o 
               ON po.order_id = o.order_id 

WHERE YEAR(o.date_ins) = 2013 and pt.available = 1 and p.status = 'shipped'

GROUP  BY pt.color,
        m.model, 
          m.gender

ORDER BY  pt.color,
        m.model, 
          m.gender
```

>

```
Public Shared Function ExecutaReader(ByVal strSQL)

        Dim strConn As String
        strConn = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("strConn")

        Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection)

        myConnection.Open()
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

        Return myReader


    End Function
```

Comment: Please show the code where you define `MyCommand`. We can't debug it if we can't see it.

Comment: Don't return the reader, consume it where you execute it. You should return something like `IEnumerable<AClassWithMeaningfulProperties>`.

Comment: It´s because I have a class where I put all the code that I use constantly.

Let me edit my original post

Comment: If you run the sql in management studio you should get the same error, except when you double click the error message it will take you to the line that is causing the error. This should help you isolate it.

Comment: @GarethD I´m running in management studio and it´s working fine!

Answer (score 0):

I think the returning table and the table models have the same column name gender

```
Try m.model As Model2, m.gender AS Gender2,
```